# How do extract query strings from URL and save them in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

In an existing page (developed manually in early 90) I have over 1500 text list similar to the one below:

```
- Abenakis, Pancake Mix (Buckwheat), 1 kg, $4.32 Add to Cart
```

and its "Add to Cart" HTML:

```
<a href="http://ww6.paymentcompany.com/cf/add.cfm?userid=87378855
&amp;product=Abenakis,+Pancake+Mix+(Buckwheat),+1+kg
&amp;price=4.32
&amp;scode=ABCD012
&amp;return=www.mysite.com/food.html">Add to Cart</a>
```

The following query strings change with every "Add To Cart" `<a>` anchor:

```
&amp;product=Abenakis,+Pancake+Mix+(Buckwheat),+1+kg
&amp;price=4.32
&amp;scode=ABCD012
```

I want to extract all elements in the URL and save them in DB table, then I can display them in a non-list way.

I thought of using Nokogiri, but based on what I have tried i didn't get it.

Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Do the URLs actually have `&amp;` or are they correct and really use `&`? That makes a difference with how solutions can be written. And, if the URL really uses `&`, then please make sure your examples reflect reality.

Comment: @theTinMan Ye, &amp; is part of the ugly URL. The examples are real & even the code is worse that u think. There is no HTML structure,no table, for sure no CSS.Every list should be in LI at least but rather each list element is an <a> tag. Imagine there are 1500 anchor tag like the one above in one page as full list of all product which has no images. Its all text as I wrote above. My goal, is display that big list in different way with categories & pagination. My initial thought was use Nokogiri, scrap the whole list & wrap each query string in proper element, such as Product Name, ...etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you can parse your URL using `URI.parse` to separate out the query terms.  Then you can create a hash from `URI::decode_www_form` and use the query terms however you like:

```
uri = URI.parse("http://ww6.paymentcompany.com/cf/add.cfm?userid=87378855&product=Abenakis,+Pancake+Mix+(Buckwheat),+1+kg&price=4.32&scode=ABCD012&return=www.mysite.com/food.html")
Hash[URI::decode_www_form(uri.query)]
# => {"userid"=>"87378855", "product"=>"Abenakis, Pancake Mix (Buckwheat), 1 kg", "price"=>"4.32", "scode"=>"ABCD012", "return"=>"www.mysite.com/food.html"}
```

Comment: Don't bother with CGI::Parse, use `hash = Hash[URI::decode_www_form('a=1&a=2&b=3')] # => {"a"=>"2", "b"=>"3"}`. It keeps it all in the URI class.

Comment: Thanks, I like this better so I've edited it into the answer above

Comment: The `Hash[]` approach though will discard duplicate keys... you can see in the Tin Man's comment that it discards the first `a` value. This will preserve duplicate keys: `URI::decode_www_form('a=1&a=2&b=3').each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), hash| (hash[key] ||= []) << value } #=> {"a"=>["1", "2"], "b"=>["3"]}`